# Key derivation on Arduino

Tags: key-derivation, pbkdf, embedded

The ATmega2560 is slow - it's a single core, 16MHz 8-bit AVR. Despite that, I need to use some encryption on it, and since it is limited to a few blocks, AES-256 can be used.

However, the key derivation is a problem. A computer can easily do a PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 with a million iterations in less than a few seconds. The Arduino struggles to perform 100 iterations in 4 seconds (to be exact, the time required with the implementation I use is 4.37s); that also applies when optimizations are enabled.

The current NIST recommendation is to use at least 10,000 iterations, in which case PBKDF2 may not be a good fit for my case.

When it comes to Key Derivation Functions, are there any solutions that are cryptographically safe for low power devices, and more generally IoT devices?

---

Since I cannot add comments I'll edit to answer them:

- I'm not sure what is meant by "if the key derivation is performed only once", so to be more precise: the key derivation is performed only once, yes, but the devices shouldn't block for more than a few seconds before it can actually be used. 4 seconds is not a lot, but I sure don't want to go over that.
- The key can - and will - be created beforehand, but it still needs to be computed each time the device is powered on. It would make absolutely no sense to store a key in plaintext.
- The device is safe from attackers while it is being used, however it may not be safe while powered off (it is meant to be plugged in, unlocked, have one or two interactions with it and powered off). I guess a similar device would be the "Mooltipass Hardware Password Keeper", except that I don't have access to smart cards nor do I intend to use it as a keyboard while an operating system is up and running. Unless I missed something though, smart cards aren't easily accessible (the SLE4442 is NOT read protected).

Comment: Re. _" It would make absolutely no sense to store a key in plaintext."_  Why? That's common in embedded. It's not plain text per se, it's a semi-opaque HEX file that <<0.1% of Arduino programmers will be able to read back (if any at all) when you set the lock bits and remove the bootloader.

Comment: The lockbits are far from being a good protection, many Chinese companies have processes to extract the data from the microcontrollers, and while you may argue that "do you really think people are going to care enough to do that?" I'd say that security is never well done if you begin by leaving holes everywhere.

Comment: @PaulUszak Seriously? Please **do not** suggest that anyone store passwords in plaintext. Just because it's common does not mean that it's good. Lots of people don't sanitize parameters either and SQLi is common, but that doesn't mean it's good or that any web dev worth their salt would _recommend_ allowing it.

Comment: It could be the very last option in case all other options have been crossed out. Using a key that is not well protected can be better than having no encryption whatsoever. Of course, you'd at least try and use a per-device key in that case, e.g. deriving that same key from a master key using the ID of the device. Recommending it *without* mentioning that this is a last resort is probably not a good idea, I certainly agree with that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The last resort would be a single, salted hash.

Comment: @forest Probably. We've been described the system, but not the use cases or threat model, so in the end what's best is still guesswork.

Comment: If you set things up so that the Arduino will not accept an externally provided key but instead requires the key to be derived on the microprocessor then fewer iterations is just fine. The iteration count is there to slow things down.  Generate an AES256 key, encrypt it using a PKDF derived key, store it on the microprocessor so that it can't be read externally.  Then when you fire up the device, you provide the password, to get the decrypt key for the internally stored AES 256 key and then use that key to encrypt / decrypt stuff.  Just make sure the key never leaves the chip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you should try and avoid deriving keys from passwords on embedded devices or passwords. There are a few strategies that could be used.

First of all, you can try and design a system that doesn't use a password. Passwords are very tricky to secure, and password hashing algorithms (or, in this case, rather Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF - need to be constantly updates / reconfigured to deal with the advance in computing power. Yes, that's not easy, but opting out would be preferable to haphazard solutions. For instance, you could input a key from an external device instead.

Second, you can try and use a password that's so strong that it doesn't require any PBKDF. Basically, you can encode a fully randomized key in such a way that you can enter it as if it is a password. The key would be 80 bits or higher of random data. The key can then be stored in e.g. a  password manager on your phone so that the user doesn't have to remember it. The "password" is now protected by a more capable device. Instead of performing a PBKDF over the password you could now perform a Key Based Key Derivation Function - that doesn't require a work factor - such as HKDF or a decode function followed by a KBKDF that uses AES in counter mode. Users will probably have to store the password in a password manager, as it would be too complex to remember.

Thirdly you can require an external device to perform most of the work of a PBKDF, and then finish the work on the device. In that case your device may have to do only one step of hashing. Instead of the password the device will receive the intermediate result and then proceeds by performing a single one-way function (such as a hash) over it. You could for instance perform PBKDF2 on a smart phone and then continue with a hash on the embedded device. Some password hash functions such as [Catena in the password hashing competition](https://www.uni-weimar.de/de/medien/professuren/medieninformatik/mediensicherheit/research/catena/) deliberately contained ways of performing such a split between client (the phone in this story) and the server (the embedded device). This solution requires that the device and connection to the embedded device is secure; it shifts the burden largely from the device to the surrounding entities.

Comment: Sorry about method #1 but it needs to be in there for future readers. And sorry to CodesInChaos for stealing his thunder in method #3.

Comment: Don't worry, I perfectly agree with method #1, it's just that getting read-protected smartcards or similar devices is pretty hard. Second method is great as it answers my [other question, on the same topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/73202/security-implications-of-using-a-high-entropy-password-with-a-low-iteration-coun), I would, however, rather remember it (it's not that hard anyway). Third method implies that the phone is safe though, as a man-in-the-middle on it could easily replay the computed hash.

Comment: Usually passwords only have an entropy of about 47 bits on average. Remembering a password with 80 bits of entropy is exceedingly hard. And usually it is not the only password that needs to be remembered.

Comment: Though, in the current case, I will be the sole user of the device. If the following calculation is correct, that is, log2(14^24) (charset of 14 characters, length of 24), then it makes _at best_ an entropy of 91 bits (one could argue that it would be lower since the password isn't entirely random). Remembering a 24 character password with the charset "123456789ABCD" isn't too difficult.

Comment: As sole user you can do what you want, but I would like to point out that humans are rather incapable of choosing ones that have high entropy, and most human minds are really more failure prone than yours.

Comment: This is really bad advice.  Externally stored keys are vulnerable and fail to meet the "Something you Know" criteria because they are instead something you have.  PKDF2 was written to be slow on purpose.

Comment: PBKDF2. PBKDF's are designed to be slow for attackers - with embedded it is mainly slow on the device, which doesn't help. Feel free to add your own answer though. Many people have smart phones with password managers, it seems silly not to use those. I personally cannot live without anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't many KDFs that will be faster on an AVR than PBKDF2. In your case, it's likely that the only thing you can do is find a hash which can be implemented efficiently on an ATmega2560, and implement it with as many optimizations as possible. A highly-optimized implementation of a hash algorithm is likely to improve speed significantly. That's really all you can do: Find/write a very fast AVR implementation.

If you find that PBKDF2-HMAC isn't giving you optimal performance, you could try to use a similar KDF such as S2K of the OpenPGP standard. It works by concatenating the password and salt and feeding that data into some chosen hash function. It is fed, repeating, until the configured number of bytes have been processed. See [RFC 4880 § 3.7.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.3) for the specifications. It does not require any optimizations beyond optimizing the hash itself, unlike PBKDF2-HMAC. Benchmark it and see if it's good for you.